# How to display different layers with different CRS in one canvas in a standalone application?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, pyqgis

I am a freshman of the  pyqgis. Now I load the raster and vector data in the standalone application. The two data are same area, but in my canvas, they are at different places. I want to know how to deal with the CRS.

Comment: There are several CRS pygis questions already in this forum. What have you already tried?

Comment: yes, I have read some, but by now I have not understand it very well

Answer (score 2):

I think ideally layers which cover the same area *should* be in the same CRS before you load it in your application (i.e. re-save vectors and reproject rasters). This is important when conducting spatial analysis. But if it's just for **displaying**, you could use the following code to set the CRS for all loaded layers and the map projection (*change the EPSG code to suit*):

```
from qgis import core
from qgis.core import QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
    layer.setCrs(QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId))

my_crs = core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326, core.QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
iface.mapCanvas().mapRenderer().setDestinationCrs(my_crs)
```

Comment: Hi Joseph, thanks for your help. I added your code into my python script. The result seems that the two data are still not projected correctly.

Comment: @Chen - You may need to save your shapefile and/or reproject your raster to the same CRS **before** loading it into your application. The code posted only displays it at a given CRS which may not match the layers correctly.

Comment: @Chen - Most welcome buddy =)